# MVN Install getting failed to resolve dependencies

Tags: jenkins

MVN clean install getting failed while downloading dependencies through POM.xml

I have tried all the guidelines while configuring project and selected option to resolve dependency while configuring build step

clean install

Expected outcome is all dependencies should be downloaded mentioned in POM.xml file and build should be successful as I do in terminal. While I create build using jenkins its not able find any of dependency or sometimes it gives "< packagename.jar> zip end header not found"

Comment: Verify that the file `~/.m2/settings.xml` is configured correctly on your build agent. If behind a corporate proxy, use the correct proxy settings. Finally, delete the local repository `~/.m2/repository` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

One of my dependency jar file was corrupted and was causing the issue.Fixing that jar file resolved the issue.